# ado.net can't read from my database

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net, connection-string

This is a really noob-problem but im tearing my hair soon.
I'm trying to read from my local database but it gives me nothing.
Here is the code:

```
protected void readBtn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ConnString = "server=localhost; Trusted_Connection=yes; database=expreimentalDB";

    string SqlString  = ("SELECT * FROM tblCity WHERE city = '@city'");

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlString, conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("city", cityTB.Text);

            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = reader;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The connectionstring should work (because if i rename the database part in the string it crashes).

The sql is working (tried it in sql manager)

reader (the SqlDataReader) is empty
What is it I havnt tried out yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the single quotes from around @city in your query so that it becomes

```
string SqlString  = "SELECT * FROM tblCity WHERE city = @city";
```

and then

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("city", cityTB.Text);
```

needs to be changed to

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", cityTB.Text);
```

Comment: Of Course, that easy (a bit embarrassing). Many thanks to you best sir!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, but shouldn't you have to prefix the name of the parameter with the @-sign when adding it to your command? Like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", cityTB.Text);
```